# How to make a device node persistent in a LXC

Tags: lxc

I need /dev/fuse inside a LXC. cgroups are properly configured, i.e. I can manually create the device node and everything is fine - until I restart the container, then the node is gone. Of course I could recreate the node using a dedicated startup script, but I expect that there is a less hacky way to achieve this.

So how to do it canonically?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Any solution yet? I guess that we have to find a way to create it during start-up every time

Answer (score 1):

If not using systemd init inside LXC 1.x container for me works:

```
lxc.autodev = 0
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:229 rwm
```

for /dev/fuse device created inside container:

```
mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229
```

Comment: This is what I did, but strangely the node is gone on every restart. I meanwhile use a script to create it on every new start. I'm using SysV init.